# Convert 14-bit image to 16-bit TIFF using C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, tiff, 16-bit, 8-bit

I have a buffer with 14-bit image (640 x 512).
I need save this image as 16-bit TIFF.

So, each pixel takes 2 bytes, and I can trasform into grayscale (8 bit) like this:

```
(buffer[index] | buffer[index + 1] << 8) & 0x3FFF
```

(`index` is number of pixel for example).

As I understand, 8-bit image I can easily save as BMP using bitmap:

```
bmp.Save("c:\\button.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

But i don`t know, how can I transform it into 16-bit TIFF. Should I transform 8-bit into 16, or 14 into 16? And how?

Somebody told me I have to form some TIFF Header and add image data to this header. Is it true? Is there any example of this? Or some library to automate this process.

Comment: You can use LibTiff .NET to save image in TIFF format: http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/ To convert 14 to 16 bit multiply every pixel (2 bytes) by 4.

Comment: @AlexFarber , thanks! why you post a comment, not an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LibTiff .NET to save image in TIFF format:

[LibTiff .NET](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/)

To convert 14 to 16 bit multiply every pixel (2 bytes) by 4.